# jQuery, bloquear cliques múltiplos no link

Tags: jquery

Estou tentando bloquear cliques múltiplos. Para botões eu consegui a solução, mas para os links ainda não tive sucesso.  Tem uma solução que desabilita o link, porém não executa a ação do link.  Tentei usar preventDefault, mas não tenho certeza de que ele resolveria o meu problema.

Solução para os botões, funciona perfeitamente.

```
        jQuery.fn.preventDoubleSubmit = function() {
          jQuery(this).submit(function() {
            console.log('preventDoubleSubmit..1');
            //alert('preventDoubleSubmit..1');
            if (this.beenSubmitted) {
              console.log('preventDoubleSubmit..2');
              //alert('preventDoubleSubmit..2');
              return false;
            } else {
              console.log('preventDoubleSubmit..3');
              //alert('preventDoubleSubmit..3');
              this.beenSubmitted = true;
            }
          });
        };

        jQuery('form').preventDoubleSubmit();
```

Solução 1 para link, não acontece nada ao clicar.

```
            $("a").click(function (e) { 
                console.log('Cliquei no link..1');
                e.preventDefault();
                var target = jQuery(this);
                console.log("You clicked!", target.length);
                target.trigger("click");
                console.log('Cliquei no link..2');
            });
```

Solução 2 para link, desabilita o link porém não executa a ação

```
            $("a").click(function () { 
                console.log('Vou desabilitar');
                $(this).fadeTo("fast", .5).removeAttr("href"); 
                return true;
            });
```

HTML

```
<a  href='<s:url action="Pedido!edit"><s:param name="id" value="id"/></s:url>'><strong>Editar</strong></a>
```

Só mais um detalhe, os links estão fora da tag form.

Comment: Na solução 2 você poderia pegar o atributo href do elemento e usar localtion.href para abrir o link depois de remover o atributo.

Comment: Matheus, você poderia me passar um exemplo de como ficaria o código?  Acho que seria uma boa solução.  Obrigado.

Comment: Seria esse o comando para abrir o link ? window.location = $(this).attr('href');

Comment: Quando dizes "cliques múltiplos" refereste a `dblclick`, ou seja o habitual clique duplo rápido?

Comment: Usuários impacientes clicam a primeira vez, após alguns segundos sem resposta, clicam novamente.  Então seria bloquear à partir do segundo clique.

Answer (score 2):

Em caso de `link` você pode utilizar o seguinte para desabilitar o click:

```
$(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
```

Em caso de botão pode ser algo como:

```
$(this).prop("disabled", true );
```

Depois que fizer executar o evento, você habilita novamente.

Comment: Léo, funcionou.  Como o link redireciona para outra página, não preciso me preocupar em habilitar novamente.  Obrigado.

Comment: @Developer se for apenas um click, você também pode utilizar a solução do colega [Wallace Maxters](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/4995/wallace-maxters).

Comment: Sim, a solução é boa.  Mas minha lista de links é criada dinamicamente (incluí a imagem com a lista na pergunta), eu teria que atribuir esse método a todos os links da página.

Answer (score 2):

Você precisa implementar um `return false` no seu evento de `click`

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var count = 0;
 $("a").click(function (evt) { 
    count++;
    if ( count > 1) {
      // Desabilita cursor
     $(this).css('pointer-events', 'none');
    return false;
 }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a  href='<s:url action="Pedido!edit"><s:param name="id" value="id"/></s:url>'><strong>Editar</strong></a>
```

Comment: Gabriel, a ideia do contador foi muito boa.  Independente do link que eu clicar, o contador sempre será incrementado e após o primeiro clique os demais serão desabilitados pelo if.  Obrigado.

Comment: Gabriel, o código funcionou perfeitamente.  Mas eu gostaria de desabilitar todos os links após o primeiro clique.  Quando criei o else para desabilitar todos "$('a').css('pointer-events', 'none');", a ação do link não está sendo executada.  Pode me dar essa ajuda?  Não tenho domínio de jQuery e javascript, minha dúvida pode ser básica.

Comment: Para desabilitar todos os botões você pode trocar a referência do seletor `$(this)`, na linha 7, para o desejado `$("a")`

Comment: Ok, eu alterei.  Mas a ação do clique não está ocorrendo, redirecionar para outra página.

Answer (score 1):

No jQuery temos uma solução pronta se você deseja um click por link, basta utilizar o método `one`.

```
$('#target').one('click', function (e)
{ 
      e.preventDefault();
      $(location).attr({href: this.href});
});
```

Comment: Wallace, teria como aplicar esse método a todos os links 'a' da página?   Obrigado.

Comment: Sim, os links têm classe?

Comment: Não, mas posso criar e associar.